# How can I change a process's BasePriority using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing an application where a user can change the Application's (process's) Basepriority

How can I do this in .Net?

Its seems I can only "get" the Basepriority value but I cant "set" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
```

i was looking at `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess ().BasePriority` which is readonly

(i know lame...)

Comment: The base priority is not the same as the priority class. The priority class partially determines the base priority.

Comment: yes i know, I was just saying that i was looking in the wrong place, by the way are you the same Mr.Wj32 processhacker fame